# Lists and unchecked conversions

Tags: java, unchecked-conversion

In trying to fix a warning about "Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List". Basically taking a List of Objects and casting it to a List of InventoryPDFAdapter.

This was the code which was throwing the warning

```
//List<InventoryPDFAdapter> invList = stratificationMap.get(stratification);
```

This is my solution

```
List untypedList = stratificationMap.get(stratification);
List<InventoryPDFAdapter> invList = new ArrayList<InventoryPDFAdapter>();
for(Object o : untypedList) {
    invList.add((InventoryPDFAdapter)o);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this while still avoiding the warning?

Comment: What is `stratificationMap`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . I'm pretty sure you can just use casting, but it would be easier to help if you made a reproducible example...

Comment: If you know for a fact that your list contains only `InventoryPDFAdapter` objects, you may just cast the entire list and insert a `@SuppressWarning` tag. If you're unsure, you should probably issue a custom error message in your loop if one object isn't.

Comment: Please post the declaration of variable `stratificationMap`.

Comment: Why do you use `List` without the generics parameter?